# How do I target input[type=checkbox] in jss

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I've tried countless things. I want to remove the ios checkbox style (the shadowy strange looking one).

```
             '&input:checked': {
                "WebkitAppearance": "none",
                "MozAppearance": "none",
                "appearance": "none",
                "borderRadius": "15px",
                "border": "1px dashed #BBB",
                "padding": "10px",
                "lineHeight": "20px",
                "textAlign": "center",
                "background": "transparent",
                "outline": "none"
            }
```

and countless other things I've found online, nothing seems to change it. I've tried digging through jss examples and no one seems to attempt to try and change those special input fields (type=text for example).

I have attempted to use online css -> jss converters too, typed in working css and the converter gives me a style that's: `input_type_checked` that also doesn't seem to target anything correctly.

Here is an example of my checkbox:

```
<label>
    <input className={classes.checkbox} type="checkbox" checked={check} onChange={() => setCheck(!check)}/>
    <p>A checkbox.</p>
</label>
```

Comment: do you mean for every single instance of checkbox, not just a specific component?

Comment: are you looking for a selector like this ?`input[type="checkbox"] { /* your styles here*/}`

Comment: specific or any, I understand that those are two different things but I can't target any of them.

Comment: @lastr2d2 yes but for jss.

Comment: You can use the [Global Plugin](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-global?v=v10.5.1) to add styles globally, in React I would suggest doing global styles on your Root component (usually `App`). For a specific class to be added to a component it should just be something like `{ myClass: { '&[type="checkbox"]': { /* styles here */ } } }` ( this would require the [Nested Plugin](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.5.1) )

Comment: If you want to specifically only change checked styling you could do `{ myClass: { '&:checked': { /* styles here */ } } }` (this would still require the Nested Plugin.

Comment: Here is an example using the react-jss codesandbox [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jss-playground-forked-4kpp6?file=/index.js)

Comment: you've already assigned a class `checkbox` to it, that should target your component assuming this jss snippet is used for the class object.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```js
//selects the first input type=text
const element = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
```

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) let you use CSS selectors in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways I would go about doing this depending on the situation:

Using the [Global plugin](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-global?v=v10.5.1) for all `checked` inputs in the app.

```js
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
    // Note: global styles will only work
    // while the containing component is in
    // the component tree. I would suggest
    // using your root component for global
    // styles in most cases.
    '@global': {
        'input:checked': {
            /* STYLES GO HERE */
        }
    }
});

const App = () => {
    // Global styles do not need to have the 
    // class names assigned to a component.
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            My App with global styles!
        </div>
    )
};
```

OR

Using the [Nested plugin](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.5.1) for a class based approach

```js
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
    check: {
        "&:checked": {
            /* STYLES GO HERE */
        }
    }
});

const MyComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div>
            My Component with class based styles!
            <input type="checkbox" className={classes.check} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

NOTE: The examples are using React JSS, to swap to material UI replace `createUseStyles` with `makeStyles`;